# Get expanded range containing all cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following situation: A named range let's say rngPM containing 5 cells spread apart like in the print screen below.

My purpose is to get a rectangular range containing the 5 cells (orange rectangle), so I can load their formulas in VBA and work with them (this requires the range to be the same area, or contiguous cells).

Is there a better/faster way to find that rectangular range, other than looping through each cell/area to get first row, last row, first column, last column, and using:

```
set rngRectangle = rngPM.parent.range(cells(firstRow,firstCol),cells(lastRow,lastCol))
```

[image]

Comment: If you know at least the position of topleftcell then you may use [RESIZE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) to get the rectangle you wish, because you know where to start (topleftcell) and how many rows and columns the rectangle will have

Answer (score 2):

Almost sure there is no build in functionality in Excel, so I would create a function for that, doing more or less what you already described: loop over all areas of the range, figure out the first and last row and column in use and create a Range from that:

```
Function getEnclosingRange(r As Range) As Range
    Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long, firstCol As Long, lastCol As Long

    ' Step 1: Find first and last row and column
    Dim area As Range
    For Each area In r.Areas
        If firstRow = 0 Or area.row < firstRow Then firstRow = area.row
        If firstCol = 0 Or area.Column < firstCol Then firstCol = area.Column
        If lastRow < (area.row + area.Rows.Count - 1) Then lastRow = area.row + area.Rows.Count - 1
        If lastCol < (area.Column + area.Columns.Count - 1) Then lastCol = area.Column + area.Columns.Count - 1
    Next
    
    ' Step 2: Create enclosing range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = r.Parent
    With ws
        Set getEnclosingRange= .Range(.Cells(firstRow, firstCol), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    End With
End Function
```